# Py2Exe cannot find a custom module

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I have the python project whose structure is as follows

[image: Project structure]

The RMsgType class is used in greet.py which is in the greet folder. I am planning to generate an exe for greet.py, so that it's easier for my end users to run this plugin. In order to do that , I have created a setup.py under the same folder as the greet.py is

However there is where I am getting stuck . What I have done till now is

1. added the following lines in the setup.py

   from log import RMsgType

   but it fails with the message "Import Error : No module named log"

[image: No module Named log]

2 . Tried removing the import statement and adding the log/ log.RMsgType in the includes but that is also failing with the message

[image: No module named log]

3. I have also tried PyCharm's Convert to package feature but that is apparently also not working.

[image: Convert to package]

I am using Py2exe to generate an exe on Windows OS of my python script.

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49640561/1647238