# py2exe specifying subfolder

Tags: python, py2exe

I want use py2exe to compile a .py script to an exe.

Filestructure:

```
ProjectDir
  - src
    - FullGui.py
    - other modules
    - setup.py
  - tools
    - Gui2exe
  - docs
```

To meet my typical workflow, I want to move the setup.py (eg. to `tools` because creation of .exe is a seperate process and not part of the software deployed).
I created the setup.py using Gui2exe. When I use it in my `src` folder, it works flawless.

```
# ======================================================== #
# File automagically generated by GUI2Exe version 0.5.3
# Copyright: (c) 2007-2012 Andrea Gavana
# ======================================================== #

# Let's start with some default (for me) imports...

from distutils.core import setup
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe

import glob
import os
import zlib
import shutil

# Remove the build folder
shutil.rmtree("build", ignore_errors=True)


class Target(object):
    """ A simple class that holds information on our executable file. """
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        """ Default class constructor. Update as you need. """
        self.__dict__.update(kw)


# Ok, let's explain why I am doing that.
# Often, data_files, excludes and dll_excludes (but also resources)
# can be very long list of things, and this will clutter too much
# the setup call at the end of this file. So, I put all the big lists
# here and I wrap them using the textwrap module.

data_files = []


includes = []
excludes = ['Tkconstants', 'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'Tkinter', '_gtkagg',
            '_gtkagg', '_tkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'bsddb',
            'curses', 'curses', 'email', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger', 'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.debugger.dbgcon',
            'pywin.dialogs', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl', 'tcl']
packages = []
dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'msvcp90.dll', 'msvcp90.dll',
                'tcl84.dll', 'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll', 'tk84.dll']
icon_resources = []
bitmap_resources = []
other_resources = []


# This is a place where the user custom code may go. You can do almost
# whatever you want, even modify the data_files, includes and friends
# here as long as they have the same variable name that the setup call
# below is expecting.

import matplotlib
data_files.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())


# Ok, now we are going to build our target class.
# I chose this building strategy as it works perfectly for me :-D

GUI2Exe_Target_1 = Target(
    # what to build
    script = "FullGui.py",
    icon_resources = icon_resources,
    bitmap_resources = bitmap_resources,
    other_resources = other_resources,
    dest_base = "FullGui",    
    version = "1.0",
    company_name = "Bytec Medizintechnik GmbH",
    copyright = "All Rights Reserved",
    name = "void",

    )

# That's serious now: we have all (or almost all) the options py2exe
# supports. I put them all even if some of them are usually defaulted
# and not used. Some of them I didn't even know about.

setup(

    # No UPX or Inno Setup

    data_files = data_files,

    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2, 
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 2,
                          "dist_dir": "dist",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                         }
              },

    zipfile = None,
    console = [],
    windows = [GUI2Exe_Target_1],
    service = [],
    com_server = [],
    ctypes_com_server = []
    )

# This is a place where any post-compile code may go.
# You can add as much code as you want, which can be used, for example,
# to clean up your folders or to do some particular post-compilation
# actions.

# No post-compilation code added


# And we are done. That's a setup script :-D
```

First step was to just move it one level up into `ProjectDir`. I changed `script = "FullGui.py",` to `script = "src\FullGui.py",`, but it does not work as expected. It compiles the .py into an .exe just fine, but aborts launch and gives following error in the log file of the exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FullGui.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "receiver.pyo", line 9, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "serial\__init__.pyo", line 18, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "serial\serialwin32.pyo", line 9, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading win32file.pyd
```

I tried to add `src` to path by `sys.path.append('src')` and messed around by adding various path, but i can't get it to find what it needs.

A hint or solution anyone?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Use the option `package_dir= { '': '../src' }` in the `setup` function, aditional you can use the option `packages` to include your custom modules inside you project.

---

### Source

From [Py2Exe documentation](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions)

> **Py2exe extends Distutils setup keywords**

and from the [Distutils documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html) you can found this option

> **package_dir** *A mapping of package to directory names* [a dictionary]

In detail with example [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages)